# How do I insert the value of an auto-increment ID column into another column on inserting into MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

The first column in my MySQL table contains an auto increment ID.  I would like to enter this value into another column when inserting a new row into the table, i.e. I need to read the value in the ID column and insert it into the next column.

Is it possible to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure some of the above answers work, but I wasn't able to work out how to implement them. I did however successfully implement a solution using `$pdo->lastInsertId()`, i.e. after executing my INSERT query I added:

```
$new_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$sth2 = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `tracks` SET `fav_id`= IF(`fav_id`=0,$new_id,fav_id) WHERE `id`=$new_id");
$sth2->execute();
```

And this sets the fav_id column of the last inserted row to the same value as the id column for this row, if fav_id has not already been set.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO table(id, same_id, col1)
(
 SELECT NULL AS id,
        (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
         FROM information_schema.TABLES
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND
               TABLE_NAME='table') AS same_id,
        "value" AS col1
);
```

EDIT: As pointed by `Jonathan Swartz` it does suffer from race condition.
To fix this use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the last inserted id and update this value in new column:

```
INSERT INTO table(id, same_id, col1)
(
 SELECT NULL AS id,
        NULL AS same_id,
        "value" AS col1
);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @var_id;

UPDATE  table
SET     same_id = @var_id
WHERE   id = @var_id;
```

Comment: Is there a danger of a race condition here - like the auto_increment changing (because of a separate insert) in between the time when it is selected and when the insert is committed?

Comment: Confirmed that it does suffer from race condition. You can see this by inserting sleep(3) for value, then doing another insert in a separate mysql shell. You'll get the same value for same_id in two rows.

Comment: @JonathanSwartz yes right. I've edited answer for fixing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

a simple trigger can do the job.

It will be called on when the row is inserted in table 1

and will take the Id from it and file insert into table 2

[check manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysqli_insert_id` if you are using `PHP` on this.

Example.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);

/* drop table */
$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The `mysqli_insert_id()` function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

Comment: Yes I am using PHP to handle the MySQL insertion.  It's not clear to me from your example where I include mysqli_insert_id.  Presumably it is after the INSERT query?  I can't tell from your answer which line handles the insertion of the column ID into the column ID2.

Comment: I am using `$id = mysqli_insert_id($sql); $sql2="UPDATE tracks SET fav_id='$id' WHERE id='$id'";` after the INSERT query, but the fav_id is still set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You may make second column autoincremented too (with matching AUTOINCREMENT initial value), with or without any keys.

Comment: You cannot have multiple auto-increment columns for same table in mysql.